# std::bind - vector as an argument in bound function

Tags: performance, c++11, vector, stl, bind

I have a question which way is the best to forward vector to bound function?

Below is code with two approaches. In production code vector will contain huge amount of data and I would like to avoid copying it as much as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void foo(const std::vector<uint16_t>& v)
{
    for(const auto& c : v)
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint16_t> vv{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

    auto f1 = std::bind(&foo, vv); // 1)
    auto f2 = std::bind(&foo, std::move(vv)); // 2)

    f1();
    f2();
}
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the code you show us? Do you just want an opinion on which of the two `std::bind` calls you should use?

Comment: Yes, I would like to read your opinions which approach is the best (from performance POV) for binding huge amount of data - like STL containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with the bound functions.

If they are going to be copied passed around (beyond the life of `vv`), this is correct (and is going to copy `vv`).

```
auto f1 = std::bind(&foo, vv); // 1)
```

This is also correct, (`vv` is not going to be copied initially at least.)

```
auto f2 = std::bind(&foo, std::move(vv)); // 2)
```

but you will not have access to `vv` after that point.

This is however the most likely scenario that I can deduce from your example:
if the bound function will be used locally while `vv` is still alive it is more likely from the example that want you want `f3` to hold a "reference" to `vv`. This is done with the `ref` convention:

```
auto f3 = std::bind(&foo, std::ref(vv));
```